# Solve $5^{x/2}-2^x=1$

Tags: exponential-function

I tried to think of it a lot but didn't get any breakthrough. I was trying with substitution method, but things were not fitting in.

Actual answer is 2

Answer (score 1):

Let $x=2u$, then the equation becomes:
$$5^u-2^{2u}=1\Rightarrow 5^u=4^u+1^u$$
Divide both sides by $5^u$,
$$1=\left(\dfrac{4}{5}\right)^u+\left(\dfrac{1}{5}\right)^u$$
Easily observe that $u=1$ is one of the answer. However, as $\left(\dfrac{4}{5}\right)^u+\left(\dfrac{1}{5}\right)^u$ is strictly decreasing, so there must only have at most one answer. Therefore the answer is $u=1$, which means that $x=2$

Comment: if you see first answer is more simple

Comment: I want to show that there is only one answer @user3290550

Comment: So I write a bit long, and I hope you will know that $x=2$ is the only answer. @user3290550

Comment: @user3290550 How would you prove that 'since they all have the same exponential, the exponential must be 1' with a simple answer?

Answer (score -1):

Rewrite,

$$5^{x/2}-2^x=1$$

as

$$5^{x/2}=4^{x/2} + 1^{x/2}$$

Since $5=4+1$ and they all have the same exponential, the exponential must be 1,

$$\frac x2=1$$

which yields

$$x=2$$

Comment: interesting approach , thanks so much

Comment: No problem. Glad it helps

Comment: can you explain"since they all have the same exponential, the exponential must be 1"

Comment: @IsaacYIUMathStudio What he's done is to simply explain the observation that one solution is $x/2=1.$ The only thing is that he didn't explain why this is the complete solution.

Comment: Thanks for explain @Allawonder

Comment: Issac, may be a little pretentious providing a similar answer from which you knew the answer to your comment.